# Mongoose date format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently having an issue retrieving dates from mongoose. This is my schema:

```
var ActivitySchema = new Schema({
    activityName      : String
  , acitivtyParticipant  : String
  , activityType  : String
  , activityDate      : { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  , activityPoint  : Number
});
```

This defaults to use "mm.dd.yyyy", so all data I have which is in format "dd.mm.yyyy" defaults to Date.now.

Does anyone know if there is a "format: "dd.mm.yyyy" function which I can put directly in the Schema? Any other ideas? (would really not like to update all the data)

Thank you for any replies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, Mongoose doesn't have a 'default format'. Instead, it saves `Date` instances as (I think) RFC 822 timestamps (`Mon Jan 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`), and parses them back from the database by running `new Date(INPUT)`.

That last action is your problem:

```
> new Date('01.02.2012')
Mon Jan 02 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

As you can see, Javascript itself parses it as `mm.dd.yyyy`. I don't know if that's solvable without having to update your database.

Comment: Not sure about 2013, but I believe today Mongoose uses ISO 8601 Format, https://www.silisoftware.com/tools/date.php

Comment: @myNewAccount I think Mongoose still relies on what `Date` supports :D