# How do I use a Date object in a Mongoose findOne() call

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a schema with a date element:

```
var a = new mongoose.Schema({
name : String,
date : Date,
});
```

I am working with data that stores the date in the format *2005-08-13*

When I insert the data, it goes in fine. I query it in mongo console, and it is there as a date (with the hours set to 12:00 etc, which is fine).

The problem is, specifically from node.js, when I try to do a lookup:

```
models('meetings').findOne({ name: result.meeting.$.name }, { date: result.meeting.$.date }, function (err, meeting) {
```

The date criteria always returns true - i.e. it always matches no matter what. In particular it thinks "2008-04-06" is a match for "2008-04-21".

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this helpful: [*Mongoose date format*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16664896/mongoose-date-format)? The [*documentation*](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/defaults.html) isn't.

Comment: Not really - the dates are in the database fine. I haven't tried to read them out yet, so I'll tackle that problem when I come to it. The problem is that the criteria specifier doesnt seem to accept the same format string as the schema when it is written to the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not including `date` in your query conditions because you're passing it into [`findOne`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) as the field selection object (second parameter).  So you're currently just querying by `name`.

Put both query conditions into a single object:

```
models('meetings').findOne(
    { name: result.meeting.$.name, date: result.meeting.$.date }, 
    function (err, meeting) { ...
```