# Query using $gt tags mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm doing a very simple query to my MongoDB where I want to find all objects with a duration above the current date. My query:

```
Campaign.find({ 'duration': { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, numAffected){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log(numAffected);
    console.log(typeof numAffected);
  }
});
```

When I run this query directly in Robomongo I get the expected result with an object which has duration greater than the current time. Also when using mongoose without the $gt-tag, I get the object that I wish to extract. The query above gives me an empty array-object.

My mongoose version is 2.4.10.

Duration object in the model looks like this:

```
duration: {
//How long should the campaign last
type: Date,
default: function(){return +new Date() + 7*24*60*60*1000;},
required: 'Please fill the duration of the Campaign. Default is 1 week.'
},
```

Comment: `Date.now()` method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC, whereas the `duration` field is a `Date` type, not a `Number` hence the query fails. What you need is a Date object that represents the current date time in your query as `Campaign.find({ 'duration': { $gt: new Date() } }, callback)`

Comment: Tried that as well. No cigar. `var dateNow = new Date();
  Campaign.find({ 'duration': { '$gt': dateNow } }, function(err, numAffected){`

Comment: If I remove the $Gt tag, and console.log() the duration-object on the desired data I get `Mon Sep 19 2016 13:04:41 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

Comment: Issue may be how mongoose stores dates, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/16665301/224370

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
{

Campaign.find({ 'duration': { "$gt" : { "$date" : new Date()}}, function(err, numAffected){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
  }else{
    console.log(numAffected);
    console.log(typeof numAffected);
  }
});
```

}